# IIS configuration in WiX

Tags: iis, configuration, wix

Is it possible to configure IIS using WiX?

If it is then how do I find out which ASP.NET and IIS features (for example, add [MIME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME) types, add application string, add connection string, etc.) can be configured in WiX?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9102164/wix-web-application-install-with-initial-iis-settings-need-upgrade-files-not

Comment: I want to know about..MIME types..Can i add MIME types by using wix?

Comment: i think so http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1751572/adding-mimemap-via-wix-failed

Comment: Ya..I got the answer..Thank you Rachel Gallen